# Extremely slow geth mining and synchronization for private blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, private-blockchain, docker

I am constructing a very simple 2 nodes private Ethereum network to study the mining behaviour. The consensus algorithm is ethash. In order for the 2 nodes to discover each other, I also setup a bootnode. All these nodes are running on different IP addresses. Basically I created a docker network and ran 1 bootnode container and 2 geth containers.

I successfully initialized the block (via geth init...), created 10 accounts for each node. Then I initiated the 2 geth instances to start mining, it went through the usual DAG generation. While generating DAG for epoch 1, the mining also started and I can see node1 mined 2 blocks and node2 mined 1 block. After DAG generation is completed, the mining simply stopped.

Here is my genesis.json file, BTW I had lowered the difficulty to 0x000010

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 5493,
    "homesteadBlock": 1,
    "eip150Block": 2,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 3,
    "eip158Block": 3,
    "byzantiumBlock": 4,
    "ethash": {}
  },
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "timestamp": "0x5a9d2b4e",
  "extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "0x47b760",
  "difficulty": "0x000010",
  "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    }
  },
  "number": "0x0",
  "gasUsed": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

Here is the screenshots of my geth console. The top is node1 and bottom is node2. The geth instances are still busy working away - my CPU utilisation is max'ed out. But for the last 15 minutes, there is no activity reported on the geth consoles.

[image: Screenshots of 2 geth consoles]

Somehow things started to move again but very slowly. 
As you see in the below screenshot, node1 continues to mine new block and it also discarded a bad propagated block (from node2). It also has some lines that said "Regenerated local transaction journal"

For node2, it also mined 1 new block and synchronised other blocks from node1. 
As shown on the screenshot, the duration between block is very long 7mins to 20 mins. There is also a sidefork on node2.

This experiment is done with plain vanilla geth, no externally triggered transferred or smartcontract call.

Is there anything I miss here? I simply want the private network to behave like the ethereum mainnet, i.e. mine new block roughly every 10 seconds.

[image: Very slow mining]
The commands to launch the various nodes are

```
bootnode
file="/root/bootnode/enode"
if [ ! -f "$file" ]
  then
    echo "initialize bootnode"
    bootnode -genkey /root/bootnode/nodekeyfile
fi
bootnode -nodekey /root/bootnode/nodekeyfile

geth node
geth --networkid 5493 --bootnodes "$(echo -n 'enode://'; bootnode --writeaddress -nodekey /root/bootnode/nodekeyfile | tr -d '\n'; echo '@192.168.2.2:30301')" --mine --rpc --rpcport "8545" --port "30303" --rpccorsdomain "*" --nat "any" --rpcapi eth,web3,personal,net --etherbase 0 --unlock "$(cat /root/.ethereum/geth/security/coinbase)" --password /root/.ethereum/geth/security/password.sec
```

I basically shared the volume where bootnode nodekeyfile is stored among the 3 containers thus they can all construct the bootnode URL. Anyway, I don't think the bootnode is the issue as the 2 geth nodes are able to talk to each other.

Comment: I cannot write a comment, so I'm doing it here. Can you share us the command line that you are using in order to launch your nodes ?

Comment: I added the command to the end of the question. I have also added new observations.

Comment: What is your hardware configuration? ie RAM, CPU. The DAG may take some time to generate but above 20 minutes is a bit too much. An intel i5 quad core 2.6Ghz with 16Gb RAM it takes less than 3 minutes to generate.

Comment: the DAG generation is fine, the slowness comes after it when 2 nodes started mining. Anyway, I am running on i7 Macbook Pro with 16GB. I have even lowered the mining difficulty to 0x00010

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue to the problem. I didn't allocate sufficient memory to my docker process. After I increased the docker memory allocation to 6GB, it works fine. Due to the lowered difficulty, I was even having blocks mined every 2 seconds.